# JPA Entites from Tables, Entites Not Correct

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a MySQL database with roughly 40 tables and a lot of foreign keys. I tried to use JPA tools "Entities from Tables" and it generated all the entities. However the entities are not correct. For whatever reason the annotations are above the get methods instead of the instance variable declaration. Also there are no foreign key relationships in the entities.

There are cases were multiple tables all have references to the one table. I don't know if that is confusing JPA tools or something. The database is MySQL 5.6 and all the tables are using InnoDB storage engine. We are planning on using Hibernate 4 JPA implementation. We used the org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect dialect setting when we did the entity generation.

I'm not sure what the issue is. A DBA reviewed the schema and we don't have much flexibility for changing the schema. Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing? Or does JPA tools just not handle complex schemas very well?

If the reverse engineering isn't viable we can just manually create the entities.

Edit:

I used JPA tools Entities from Tables once before on a small database, less than 10 tables with a minimum number of foreign keys, and it worked flawlessly.

Edit 2:

I have two tables for users and roles, Users and Roles.

The User entity should have something like this

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Instead this is what it generated in the Role entity

```
@Column(name="UserID", nullable=false)
private int userId;
```

There is a foreign key from UserID in Role table to ID in User table. This is happening for all foreign keys though. The reverse engineered entities have no foreign key relationships.

Comment: IMO, I think JPA works better if you generate the tables from the entities. You should try other JPA implementations such as openJPA. Please provide more details about your schema and what exactly "entities are not correct" means.

Comment: _For whatever reason the annotations are above the get methods instead of the instance variable declaration_ this is because tool probably is used AccessType.PROPERTY, and the Annotation with this accessType are over the get methods.

Comment: Based on your second update, it seems that the tool that are you using it is not working properly, try to generate them by yourself or consider using another tool or tune a little bit the configuration,

Answer (score 0):

Most of the modern days IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse, etc are pretty much capable to generate Entity from the database automatically(using option `create entity from tables`).

Different IDEs are having different default settings for the Entity generation. Also it has the option to allow you to add/remove few options as well. Entity generated from Eclipse will differ from the one comes from Netbeans(or other IDE). But whatever entities they are generating, are correct.

So, when you are generating entity automatically, just make sure you have chosen the right options for you. If not, then change the entity manually after generation. Instead of developing all the entities from the scratch, its always better to have some baseline, and then edit if you need.

Comment: I'm using the JPA Tools which I believe is part of the jBoss tools for Eclipse plugin. Any other suggestions on tools / plugins for eclipse?